# Nginx load balancing does not forward correctly

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

Nginx forwards call in a wrong way when configured with upstream!

***Not working***

```
upstream search {
  server some.server.com;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://search;
  }
}
```

***Working good***

```
upstream search {
  server some.server.com;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://some.server.com;
  }
}
```

When configured with upstream - target server returns "404 - Resource not found"

**What do I do wrong?**

Comment: Can you provide nginx log file (info level)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in 'HOST' header

in case of upstream header 'HOST' is set to search.

To fix that you need to replace 'HOST' header in request

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header Host  some.server.com;
  proxy_pass  http://search;
}
```